# jquery toggle works on part of the div only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an issue concerning jquery toggle.

It seems it doesn't include the skills.

```
<section class="ResumeItem">
      <header class="ResumeContentTitle" id="ResumeKnowledgeHeader">
          <p>Professional Knowledge</p>
      </header>
      <section class="skills">
           <header>
               <h3>Strong Skills</h3>
           </header>
           <ul>
               <li>PHP</li>
               <li>jQuery</li>
               <li>SQL</li>
               <li>Ajax</li>
               <li>HTML</li>
               <li>CSS</li>
            </ul>
      </section>

      <section id="ResumeKnowledge" class="ResumeContentText">
            <ul>
               <li>PHP – Expert Strong level. Worked with this technology for over a year.</li>
            </ul>
      </section>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
   $('.ResumeContentTitle').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id').split('Header');
      $('#'+id[0]).toggle("slow");
   });
});
```

here is an example :
http://jsfiddle.net/ohadpartuck/R2cEd/

Comment: Well of course it won't. The skills section isn't inside the section that is being hidden.

Comment: Explain your issue, in your link toggle is on #ResumeKnowledge, but this div didn't include the skills list.

Comment: Your code is working as expected. you are applying toggle only on section with id ResumeKnowledge.

Comment: You need to include you code in the question in case the jsfiddle link disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the skills is not selected since you havent included them just include them

working  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/ghQxp/  or http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/hNKpq/

```
$(function(){
   $('.ResumeContentTitle').click(function(){

      $(".skills ,.ResumeContentText").toggle("slow");


   });
});
```

Comment: it's not me but i think because you forgot the id var (unused)

Comment: I didn't downvote either but you've over simplified the OPs code. Their code is taking the ID from the div that is being clicked, I assume so they can split it off into a separate function and use it for many divs.

Answer (score 0):

As I take it that your code is intended to be reused for other boxes the other answers won't really help you.

What I have done is added an ID to the skills section and added that to the javascript to the first part of the ID will be taken from the div that was clicked on as you have done but I've added the word skills to the end so it will hide that too.

HTML

```
<section class="ResumeItem">
                    <header class="ResumeContentTitle" id="ResumeKnowledgeHeader">
                        <p>Professional Knowledge</p>
                    </header>
                    <section class="skills" id="ResumeKnowledgeSkills">
                        <header>
                            <h3>Strong Skills</h3>
                        </header>
                        <ul>
                            <li>PHP</li>
                            <li>jQuery</li>
                            <li>SQL</li>
                            <li>Ajax</li>
                            <li>HTML</li>
                            <li>CSS</li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>

                    <section id="ResumeKnowledge" class="ResumeContentText">

                        <ul>
                            <li>PHP – Expert Strong level. Worked with this technology for over a year.</li>

                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </section>​
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
   $('.ResumeContentTitle').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id').split('Header');
      $('#'+id[0]).toggle("slow"); 
      $('#'+id[0]+'Skills').toggle("slow"); 
   });

});​
```

jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/R2cEd/10/